# Java , J2EE , Javax FX , Maven : Can't find bundle for base name .. the great black hole?

Tags: maven, javafx, java-8, resourcebundle

using eclipse 4.10 (2018-12), java 8 (jvm & eclipse runtime) ,  on debian 9 stations I'm developing an application.

Everything is right with the "core" object collection (beans , Dao , J2EE web interfaces) . 
the application being growing up I need now graphical and event aware javafx application approach. BUT .. when dealing with java ResourceBundle (internationalization messages and configuration purpose) .. things went wrong.

my question is how to deal with such resources management issues through jar imports ?

the main project structure is :

[image]

mission-web.... applications J2EE works fine using maven core dependencies. All classes can access "core"'s RessourceBundle(s) included in the core's executable jar exported in missions-web/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib

mission-app (JAVAFX) .. can not.

We have dig into ClassLoader's concepts getClaas / getRessourceAsStream and so on ,  the fact is we're stucked on this architecture we've moved from python3 due to this incapacity to share this property files resources across application modules.

the core pom file (maven) is pretty simple and do it's job , build is ok and provides all functionalities to the J2EE application (ResourceBundle aware)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.open-si</groupId>
    <artifactId>missions-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.2</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/configuration</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/application.properties</include>
                    <include>**/database.properties</include>
                </includes>

            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rabbitmq/amqp-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

the J2EE web (missions-web pom file is as bellow and the application works fine and can access "core"'s resources

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.open-si</groupId>
    <artifactId>missions-web</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                            </includes>
                            <targetPath>WEB-INF/classes</targetPath>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.websocket/javax.websocket-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.open-si</groupId>
            <artifactId>missions-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.uadetector/uadetector-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.uadetector</groupId>
            <artifactId>uadetector-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.22</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.uadetector/uadetector-resources -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.uadetector</groupId>
            <artifactId>uadetector-resources</artifactId>
            <version>2014.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

the gui one's (Javafx based) fails to find resources bundles

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.open-si</groupId>
    <artifactId>missions-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.open-si</groupId>
            <artifactId>missions-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

any help is welcome. thanks in advance

Comment: first you should follow conventions over configuration which means locate your code into `src/main/java` your resources into `src/main/resources` etc..

Comment: thanks for your answer . Actually the project structure was build by the eclips(fx) plugin .. and I've found out the issue .. due to my own coding.

Answer (score 0):

after digging I've found A workaround : the resources (aplication configuration resourceBundle was invoked inside a default interface method (>= java 8). Adding a "getConf()" method without implementation returning the resource required did the trick. I think in that way the default class loader inside the jar did the job... not sure of the pure coding partterns, but it works ^^

```
public interface MyInterface {

    public interface MyInterface {

        default jobToDo(){

            ResourceBundle conf = ResourceBundle.getBundle("configuration.application");
            .. 
            // fails
        }
    }
```

BUT solved the issue .. actually not a maven problem ...

```
public interface MyInterface {

    ResourceBundle getConf(); // provided by the implementation class using the right class loader I think

    default jobToDo(){

        ResourceBundle conf = getConf();
        .. 
        // works fine
    }
}
```